# Grails-IDE Eclipse Plugin development status?

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy, eclipse-plugin, grails-plugin

I understand that [Groovy Development Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/groovy-development-tools) Eclipse plugin is still being maintained by Pivotal teams, since it had a release version just yesterday in January, 6, 2020. Unfortunatelly, this plugin does not provide Grails support and the overview details at [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/) states that as I quote:

> GDT does not provide any direct support for Grails. If you want Grails tooling, then please consider [Groovy-Grails Tools Suite](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/groovygrails-tool-suite-ggts-eclipse) or [spring-projects/grails-ide](https://github.com/spring-projects/grails-ide) for your Grails projects.

My Eclipse instalation is the latest one, 4.14 nowadays, with several plugins that relies on this very same version such as RedHat Codeready for example, so downgrading to Eclipse Juno and finding compatible version for each one of the plugins I use is not an option. Plus, IntelliJ purchase wasn't authorized and NetBeans is by far the least used IDE nowadays to reach for community help.

That being said I had one last option which was [spring-projects/grails-ide](https://github.com/spring-projects/grails-ide), but when I accessed this URL I found that the last commit was in March, 20, 2019, almost a year ago, which leads me to think that the release version is not ready for Eclipse 4.14. Besides that I can't even find the plugin overview in [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/).

1. Does anyone know information on this plugin?
2. Is it still being currently maintained? If not, which was the last Eclipse and Grails versions
   supported?
3. Does anyone suggests an alternative plugin to work with Grails and Eclipse that has syntax highlighting, code completion and that enables to use a grails compiler so as to see possible syntax problems in development phase?

**This is not a question of which IDE or plugin is better, I just need orientation, since I don't really work with Grails a long time and now the time to come back has come.**

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/grails-ide/issues/7

Comment: If you post this as answer, I'll accept it as the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Grails IDE issue #7: ***Is this project still alive?***](https://github.com/spring-projects/grails-ide/issues/7)

Currently, there seems to be no Eclipse IDE support for the current Grails version. Hopefully, one day there will be a Grails [language server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) to have Grails support in Eclipse and other IDEs and editors (similar to Rust where a language server is shipped together with the Rust compiler).

Comment: Just what I needed to know. Thankk you very much!

Comment: GitHub's spring-projects/grails-ide contains all the plug-ins that Pivotal once maintained as the Grails part of GGTS.  As with groovy/groovy-eclipse, Pivotal is no longer putting resources into Groovy/Grails.  So you or anyone could make improvements and submit them as pull requests to the GitHub project.  Groovy Development Tools (aka groovy/groovy-eclipse) has new releases only because of open-source contributions.